# Multiple line message in cordova notification

Tags: android, ios, cordova, notifications, cordova-plugins

I want to show a notification in Intel XDK by using Cordova Notification plugin with multiple line message like:

- Line 1
- Line 2
- Line 3

I had search around and try resolutions like using "\n" or "\r\n" or "\n" but all of them not working.

What should I to solve this problem or Cordova Notification plugin not supported multiple line message?

Comment: use <br> tag to break it

Comment: I had tried it and not working :)

Comment: which plugin are you using. pls share the plugin link

Comment: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-dialogs

I used this plugin which include in Intel XDK

Answer (score 3):

**This doesn't work**

```
navigator.notification.alert("break<br>the line",null,"Test","OK");
```

**This works**

```
navigator.notification.alert("break \r\n the line",null,"Test","OK");
```

Comment: I had used your code, but it's not working :(. Could you so me the example page or source about this?? Thank you ^^